# Wireguard VPN in AWS with split tunnelling not working

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-web-services, wireguard

Before I kick this off. I have very limited network knowledge so hopefully I explain my situation clearly

**THE STORY**

We currently have a very basic implementation of a site in AWS. We followed best practices, by placing all private resources (db, cache, etc) in our private subnets and allow the public subnet instances access to these resources using ec2 security groups.

However we do have the following requirement:

1. Need to access to private resources in the private subnet (like the database for example) from our dev environment
2. Access to our sites admin page. This is currently primitively secured by use of an environment variable in the application that holds an allowed list of ip addresses that can access the admin site. Over time the idea is to separate out the admin portion from the client site and provision that in a separate setup that is only accessible via VPN

So after researching this I decided to give Wireguard a go. It seems to be the new kid on the block with a lot of [promise](https://www.techadvisor.com/news/vpn/what-is-wireguard-3788133/) around performance, etc.

The ultimate win would be to set up split tunnelling that will only route the required traffic through the VPN so we do not rake up AWS bills for data transfer, etc.

After playing around for hours I found the following [article](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/02/wireguard-with-aws-private-subnets/) to set up the split vpn for internal resources and was super excited to see it working as expected (also dug around and found some great resources on ip tables) However my problems started when attempting to use the VPN to access the admin panel. I assigned a public ip to the wireguard instance, added the ip to the whitelisted environment array on the site and thought that would be that. However I quickly discovered that I could not route domain names as this is not supported. After all, it says Allowed IPs not Allowed Domains

After this I played around by allowing all traffic through the client interface using the `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0` setting and then discovered that nothing works. I then added a DNS entry to point to the wireguard server DNS (`1.1.1.1`) and I could browse again. I then proceeded to attempt to connect to the admin site (the wireguard server IP was added to the whitelist configuration for the site) and I could **not** access it. However if I curl the admin url from the wireguard server instance, I can access it.

After looking into the logs on the server, I could see that I am using the public IP for my ISP, which is why I am not getting access to the admin page. If I do a `route get` to my application ip from my machine,  I can see it is indeed using the tunnel interface on my machine.

**THE QUESTION**

1. How do I get my machine to "use" the ip address of the wireguard instance when connected
2. How do I go about resolving a Domain to use split tunnelling to connect to the application.

Ideally these questions will not require extensive setup on the peer machine. This should be a simple config upload on the peer host as we do not have control off the local machines or the OS that they are using (Some use mac, others use windows, etc)

**SOME CONFIG**

Here is my configuration before attempting to allow all through the VPN

**Server wg0.conf file**

```
[Interface]
## My VPN server private IP address ##
Address = 10.0.10.2/32

# IP forwarding
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# IP masquerading
PreUp = iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE

# firewall local host from wg peers
PreUp = iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -j REJECT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i wg0 -j REJECT

# firewall wg peers from other hosts
PreUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j REJECT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j REJECT

## My VPN server port ##
ListenPort = 51820

## VPN server's private key ##
PrivateKey = SomeServerPrivateKey

# Peer 1
[Peer]
PublicKey = SomePeerPublicKey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.10.1/32
```

**Peer Config File (My Local)**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = SomePeerPrivateKey
Address = 10.0.10.1/32
#DNS = 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = SomeServerPublicKey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.0/24
```

Comment: Your firewall rules are set to deny all traffic. I’m not sure about your subnets: What’s the virtual network subnet in AWS? Whats the subnet on the VPN link? They should be non-overlapping and the clients must know (`AllowedIPs`) about the AWS subnet _and_ the VPN subnet.

Comment: @DanielB I believe those are to reject peer to peer networking. Even if I remove them, the problem is still there. The AWS Subnet VPN is 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.4.0/24 so they should not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your iptables `MASQUERADE` rule means that your client will use the IP address of the WireGuard server when connecting through it
2. Put the IP address (or block) of every remote host you want to connect through WireGuard in the client's `AllowedIPs` setting

Say the IP address of this admin site you want to connect to is `10.1.2.3`. Add `10.1.2.3` to the client's `AllowedIPs` setting:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.0.1.0/24, 10.1.2.3
```

Now when you try to reach anything in the `10.0.1.0/24` block, or connect to your admin site (`10.1.2.3`) from your client, your client will send that traffic through WireGuard.

The iptables rules you have set up on your WireGuard server will mark all packets coming into your server from its WireGuard interface, and rewrite the source address of those packets when they leave (as long as they don't also leave through the WireGuard interface) to use the server's own IP address (specifically, the IP address of the interface through which they leave):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE
```

You can verify that your client is using the WireGuard server's IP address to connect to your admin site by running this command on the WireGuard server:

```
sudo tcpdump -niany 'host 10.1.2.3'
```

When you attempt to connect to the admin site from your client, you should see output like the following from tcpdump, showing that your client's WireGuard IP address (`10.0.10.1`) has been rewritten to use the IP address of the server's physical Ethernet interface (`10.0.1.99` in this example) when the connection is forwarded to the admin site (`10.1.2.3`):

```
12:34:56.123456 IP 10.0.10.1.44444 > 10.1.2.3.80: Flags [S], seq ...
12:34:56.123457 IP 10.0.1.99.44444 > 10.1.2.3.80: Flags [S], seq ...
12:34:56.123458 IP 10.1.2.3.80 > 10.0.1.99.44444: Flags [S.], seq ...
12:34:56.123459 IP 10.1.2.3.80 > 10.0.10.1.44444: Flags [S.], seq ...
12:34:56.123460 IP 10.0.10.1.44444 > 10.1.2.3.80: Flags [.], ack ...
12:34:56.123461 IP 10.0.1.99.44444 > 10.1.2.3.80: Flags [.], ack ...
```

If the WireGuard server connects to the admin site over the Internet, and you've assigned a public IP address (say `203.0.113.123`) to the WireGuard server, AWS will rewrite traffic from the WireGuard server to the Internet using that public IP; so from the perspective of the admin site, the connection will appear to be coming from that public IP (`203.0.113.123`).

If the admin site is also hosted in AWS, however, and you use the private IP address of the admin site to connect to it, the connection will appear to be coming from the WireGuard server's private IP address (`10.0.1.99`).